# How do I enable 2Checkout to accept Billing / Shipping Address for all Countires across the world?

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I am using "ConvertPlus Default" Checkout Theme in 2Checkout to accept international payments from my customers across the world. I generated the Buy Link and integrated with my store.

My issue is that the Checkout Form is not showing fields to input Address and City for many countries including Mexico, Japan etc. Refer screenshot below:

[image]

How do I enable the option to accept Complete Address information for all countries across the world?

Buy Link looks like this:

```
https://secure.2checkout.com/checkout/buy/?merchant=\[MerchantID\]&prod=\[ProductID\]&qty=1&tpl=default
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the tangible parameter

Send tangible=TRUE or tangible=1 for products that require physical delivery.

Answer (score 0):

As of **10/01/2019** the parameter you will need to enable shipping is

```
li_#_tangible
```

The documentation says this.

> Specifies if the corresponding li_#*type is a tangible or intangible.
>   ( Must be Upper Case, ‘Y’ or ‘N’, if li*#_type is ‘shipping’ forced to
>   ‘Y’.)

Where `#` is the parameter number. Because you can send multile items in the same `POST` so it will appear as multiple items in the 2CO cart.

Here is the full documentation about parameters,
https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/checkout/parameters/

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers.